# Koppel's gender in "In der Eckerkoppel"

Tags: gender, grammatical-case

In Hamburg there is a street called Eckerkoppel.  According to [dict.leo.org](http://www.dict.cc/?s=koppel), *Koppel* is a neuter noun.  So if a German writes "Sein Haus ist in der Eckerkoppel", is the street name treated as a feminine noun simply because it's a street?

Comment: dict.leo.org says "_die_ Koppel" for _paddock_.

Answer (score 11):

In german, there's both

> das Koppel (in english: belt)

and

> die Koppel (in english: paddock, see Hendrik's comment)

with the grammatical gender as sole difference between them.

In connection with locations or street names, „Koppel“ usually originates from the second variant. I don't know any example for „Koppel“ as part of a street name in the first sense.

There are also examples for the usage of the word „Gürtel“ to name streets (see [Kölner Gürtel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6lner_G%C3%BCrtel) or the [Wiener Gürtelstraße](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_G%C3%BCrtelstra%C3%9Fe)) or locations (see [Grüngürtel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%BCng%C3%BCrtel), „[Speckgürtel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speckg%C3%BCrtel)“, similar as "[Bible Belt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_belt)" in english).

Comment: Wow, never heard *das Koppel* for *belt*. +1 for the great explanation ;)

Comment: Thank you.  I looked at a list of entries on dict.leo.org that said "das Koppel", and in the middle of them was one that said "die Koppel", which I missed.

Comment: @OregonGhost: ask anyone who did military service - at least that's where I learned that term.

Comment: @Jan: Will do ;)

Comment: @OregonGhost Pferde stehen mit einer Koppel auf der Koppel.

Answer (score 1):

No, here "Koppel" is female.

For example, it would be correct to say "sein Haus ist im Pulverhofsweg", because "Weg" is male.